# How could I explain this situation in email?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, writing, email, subcontinental-english

My PM given me project and told me develop new project using existing code, but existing project is not good written. I mean they written very difficult code for very simple things.

I am quiet confuse, how could i write in mail that the existing project is not worth using.

Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The code of the current project is written badly. Almost all functionality is written with very values of Big O. It should be better to simplify the code by starting from scratch and using the good code snippets from it.

P.S.You can't tell them, that you are not going to use any code from the current project, simply because of the rules of code re-usability. Anyway this is not a question about English language, but about advice in your situation. Better look for answer in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Something along the lines of:

> thanks for forwarding me the existing project that will serve as a great base for the new developments you requested

Otherwise my advice would be do **not** say that you are not going to use it, you don't need to: if indeed you manage to do your project more quickly without reusing the old code, he won't care, as long as it's done and done well.